# How to get the customer ID for search query?

Tags: magento2.3, customer, search

I want to collect the customer based search query in Magento 2. In the database, I can see the table, search_query but in the table I can't see the customer ID field. In order to get the customer based search query, what I have to do?

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column to search_query table, something like customer_id,
then you should find a place where Magento log(fill) search_query table, add fill this previously added column.